# How to sort the dates in desc order in php

Tags: php

I am trying to sort the dates from my result array.

The some part of my code .

```
  foreach($merge as $key => $msg_row){
    echo'<pre>';print_r(strtotime($msg_row['created'])); 
    }
```

What code should i do for further process of date sorting ?

Comment: Okay.. thanks for down vote.

Comment: You didn't tell us what's working or not, the results you're getting and expecting to get. Btw,.. you going to mark any of your other questions as solved? *"What code should i do for further process ?"* - To do what exactly?

Comment: For date sort @Fred-ii-.

Comment: date sort how? that's rather broad. See Jay's answer. you should have clarified that in your question and not in comments or title.

Comment: Have you any idea??

Comment: [*Yes, right here...*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39724642/1415724)

Comment: I have to ask: Are you always that way @RanaAalamgeer or do you feel you're just "too cool" for the community that you can't be bothered?

Comment: @Fred-ii- i am in problem and tension and please don't spoil my mood just leave it and do yr work what you want to do, I don't ask this question only to you, and this community is not your fathers.Okay go now.

Comment: @Fred-ii- please don't comment on my any question in future.

Comment: @RanaAalamgeer You have the nerve to tell me that *lol!!!* wow... you expect us to do the work for you? Not me man, not me. You can go not me, so don't give me no lip you spoiled child. Let's keep Stack the success it is by encouraging people and not just taking their code and running away. Your questions are all still considered open and unsolved, which people will have a tendancy to waste their time to post more answers. You're not going to waste my time, that's for sure. You want FREE help; then do it yourself, or REWARD people who have given of their gracious time for you.

Answer (score 2):

To sort data in an array you will need a function to compare the dates:

```
function dateCompare($a, $b) {
    // newest dates at the top
    $t1 = strtotime($a['created']);
    $t2 = strtotime($b['created']);
    return $t2 + $t1; // sort ascending
}
```

You call this function using [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
usort($array, 'dateCompare');
```

Comment: wondering if we'll see that cool shade of jade next to this ;-)

Comment: I for one like this answer and it will work well for a project I have coming up. I for one would like to thank you Jay for taking of your (free) time; it hasn't gone to deaf ears.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort like this:

```
<?php
    $sortdate = array(
        '17/08/2015',
        '02/01/2017',
        '05/02/2014'
    );

    function sortFunction($a, $b)
        {
        $datea = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $a));
        $dateb = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $b));
        if ($datea == $dateb)
            {
            return 0;
            }

        return ($datea < $dateb) ? 1 : -1;
        }

    usort($sortdate, "sortFunction");
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($sortdate);

?>
```

- Demo link: http://codepad.org/EFIilESt